# Regex Matching of Optional Character in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm using PHP's regex preg_match() to try to match a string that occassionally contains a hyphen in the middle. The alphanumeric pattern is consistent: 3 letters followed by 3 numbers and one (optional) last letter  Example:

```
RTE234
RTE-234  

OR

DGF123R
DGF-123R
```

My database saves the string without any dash, but the string's datasource is now starting to *sometimes* include it. So my pattern that had previously been working:

```
preg_match_all("/\b\(?([a-z0-9-]+)\)?\b/i", $subject, $matches);
```

needs to be adjusted, but I'm not exactly sure how to form the multi-bracketed string which allows for an optional hyphen. My first attempt ...

```
preg_match_all("/\b([a-z]{3}[-]?[a-z0-9-]+)\b/i", $subject, $matches);
```

As you see, I can be more detailed about the first 3 letters - [a-z]{3} - but the optional dash syntax is what I'm not sure about - [-]?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found a old solution maybe u can try this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007302/regex-how-to-match-an-optional-character

Comment: It does not make sense to put a single character in a character class (except for a dot which may be a preference), so you should use `-?`. Note that `[a-z0-9-]+` will also match letters, digits and hyphens. The result is that you aren't specific enough in your regex.

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you are sure that `$subject` contains only this kind of data then you may use `^$` instead of that ugly `\b`.

Comment: Did you try your expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple pattern that matches would be

```
"\b[a-z]{3}-?[0-9]{3}[a-z]?\b"
```

You do not need brackets for matching a single character like `-` in this case, just use `a?`, `b*`, `c{3}` or whatever you'd like to match.

Answer (score 0):

you need next preg_match:

```
preg_match_all('/\b[a-z]{3}-?\d{3}[a-z]?\b/i', $subject, $matches);
```

Comment: `\w` also matches digits and underscores.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably want to save the string without any dash, you can do it in two groups:

```
preg_match_all('/\b(\w{3})-?(\d{3}\w?)\b/i', $subject, $matches);
```

and call the two subgroups to create the string without any dash:

```
$ubject2 = $matches[1].$matches[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

> The alphanumeric pattern is consistent: 3 letters followed by 3 numbers and one (optional) last letter

```
/[a-z]{3}\d{3}[a-z]?/
```

> occassionally contains a hyphen in the middle

```
/([a-z]{3})-?(\d{3}[a-z]?)/
```

In code:

```
if (preg_match('/([a-z]{3})-?(\d{3}[a-z]?)/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1] . $matches[2];
}
```