# How to modify Validation Regular Expression for form COMMA user input in ASP.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms

Numbers with 4 or more digits require a comma in this form. I need to remove this requirement but allow for commas **if** the user inputs it.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCharges" CssClass="input" placeholder="Fee" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>  
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCharges" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCharges" ValidationGroup="SaveClaim" 
                    ErrorMessage="Fee is Required" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpName" runat="server"     ErrorMessage="Fee Format 9,999.99 or 9999" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtCharges"     ValidationExpression="^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d{2})?$" ValidationGroup="SaveClaim" ForeColor="Red" />
```

Comment: add `\?` after your `comma` to denote it as optional character

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007302/regex-how-to-match-an-optional-character) article on how to make a character optional

Comment: Thank you Techspider. So write it like this "^\d{1,3}(?:,\?d{3})?(?:\.\d{2})?$" ? after the , symbol?

Comment: `^\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})?(?:\.\d{2})?$` should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make any character / group optional in `RegEx`, you have two options:

1. Use `{0,1}` to let it know that the character preceding can max occur 1 time.
2. Use `?` This metacharacter allows you to match either zero or one of the preceding character or group

In your case, you need to change your expression in the below way to let browser indicate your `,` is optional.

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})?(?:\.\d{2})?$
```