# Optional matching in regex

Tags: python, regex

Attempting to match these input strings into three matching groups ([Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/NutuSR/1)):

```
    | input string  | x  | y   | z  |
------------------------------------
  I | a             | a  |     |    |
 II | a - b         | a  | b   |    |
III | a - b-c       | a  | b-c |    |
 IV | a - b, 12     | a  | b   | 12 |
  V | a - 12        | a  |     | 12 |
 VI | 12            |    |     | 12 |
```

So the anatomy of the input strings is as follows:

> - optional first part with free text up until a `hyphen` with surrounding whitespace (`-`) *or* the input string ends
> - optional second part with *any character* after the first hyphen with surrounding whitespace up until a `comma` or the input string ends
> - optionally exactly two digits at the end

I've tried a plethora of different solutions, this is my current attempt:

```
^(?P<x>.*)(?:-)(?P<y>.*)(?<!\d)(?P<z>\d{0,2})(?!\d)$
```

It handles scenarios `II`, `IV` and `V` OK (must do some trimming of white space as well), however:

- `I` and `VI` are not returned at all
- `III` is not split at the first hyphen but at the last

Comment: You can use the `?` character in order to indicate an optional character (group). See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007302/regex-how-to-match-an-optional-character).

Comment: Your problem with III can be fixed by changing your second group to `(?:\s+-\s+)` so the whitespace is actually tested for. But your spec says *or* and *optionally* a few times, and I see no optional groups. A couple of assertions yes, but not enough to do what you need. Pre-screening could catch cases I and VI with a simple `^[\w]+$`

Comment: Check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NutuSR/2).

Comment: Give that one a try: `^(?P<x>[a-z]*)(\s\-\s)?(?P<y>[a-z\-]*)(,\s)?(?P<z>\d{0,2})?$`. You say that the second group can contain *any* character but obviously it can't because you also say the 2nd and 3rd group are delimited by a comma. This would mean your regex definition is ambiguous. Also you should be clear about what "free text" means rather than just matching `.*`.

Comment: Could you add the expected result for `b, 12`

Comment: Also what are results for the strings: `" - , 12"`, `"b, "` and `"a - "`? Are they supposed to match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to do reasonably well:

```
^(?:(.*?)(?: - |$))?(?:(.*?)(?:, |$))?(\d\d$)?$
```

The values of interest will be in groups 1, 2 and 3, respectively.

The only culprit is that "two digits" will be

- in group 2 for case V and
- in group 1 for case VI,

the other groups being empty in those cases.

This is because "two digits" happily matches the *"free text until the delimiter, or the string ends"* rule.

You could use negative look-aheads to force the two digits into the last group, but unless "two digits" aren't legal values for groups 1 and 2, this will not be correct. In any case it would make the expression unwieldy:

```
^(?:((?!\d\d$).*?)(?: - |$))?(?:((?!\d\d$).*?)(?:, |$))?(\d\d$)?$
```

---

Breakdown:

```
^                    # string starts
(?:(.*?)(?: - |$))?  # any text, reluctantly, and " - " or the string ends
(?:(.*?)(?:, |$))?   # any text, reluctantly, and ", " or the string ends
(\d\d$)?             # two digits and the string ends
$                    # string ends
```

Comment: Great answer. I was struggling with the same ambiguity regarding the "_free text until the delimiter, or until the string ends_" clause matching the digits as well. Here's your [expression visualized](https://regexper.com/#(%3F%3A(.*%3F)(%3F%3A%20-%20%7C%24))%3F(%3F%3A(.*%3F)(%3F%3A%2C%20%7C%24))%3F(%5Cd%5Cd%24)%3F%24) at a handy site I often used when working with regexes.

Comment: (Please don't downvote without leaving a comment about what's wrong. Thank you.)

Comment: Good solution! Would be nice to keep the named groups in their adequate buckets as I have to do post-checking of the types

Comment: I didn't downvote but this answer maybe came a bit too fast as the regex definition in the question is broken. It speaks about "any character" in the 2nd part but also that a 3rd part would follow the 2nd. By definition of "any character" this 3rd part can never be matched and will always be included in the 2nd. So the regex definition really needs some clarifications.

Comment: @salient You can do that, but then you must make more specific statements about what's allowed/not allowed in groups 1 and 2. If you say *"may not contain exactly two digits"* then it would resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @a_guest It says "...up until", which I mentally treat as `*?`. Actually this question has a pretty solid input definition, unlike most regex questions here, but you are right, there is still some wiggle room

Comment: Ah sorry for that ambiguity. Hope this can clear things up: The "two digits" has precedence (i.e. if "b" in `II` equaled to exactly two digits, then we would classify it into the `z`-group).

Comment: @salient see modified answer, I've added a variant that pushes two digits into the last group.

Comment: @Tomalak Okay fair point, I didn't interpret it as such. So any character but a comma. Still a definition of "free text" is required (upper- / lowercase, digits?).

Comment: @a_guest "free text" parses as `.*` for me. "free text until X" as `.*?X`. It's not watertight as far as definitions go, but it comes pretty close.

Answer (score 3):

There are less verbose regexes that achieve this task, but this one encodes the logic in a pretty straightforward fashion:

```
^(?P<x>(?!\d\d$)(?:(?! - ).)*)?(?: - (?P<y>(?!\d\d$)[^,\n]*)?(?:, )?)?(?P<z>\d\d)?$
```

---

```
^                   # assert start of string/line
(?P<x>              # capture in group "x"
    (?!\d\d$)       # if the whole string is just two digits, don't capture them in group x
    (?:             # as long as...
        (?! - )     # ...we don't come across the text " - "...
        .           # ...consume the next character
    )*
)?                  # make group x optional
(?:                 # if possible...
     -              # consume the " - " separator
    (?P<y>          # then capture group "y"
        (?!\d\d$)   # again, only if this isn't two digits which belong in group z
        [^,\n]*     # consume everything up to a comma
    )?              # group y is also optional
    (?:, )?         # consume the ", " separator, if present
)?
(?P<z>              # finally, capture in group "z"...
    \d\d            # ...two digits...
)?                  # ...if present
$                   # assert end of string
```

Comment: This answer forestalls that two digits are illegal values for groups 1 and 2. This wasn't part of the requirement, so... (comments are better than downvotes, aren't they? Especially when there are multiple ways of interpreting the question)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, this is the solution I came up with:

```
^
    (?:(?P<x>\D*?)(?=(?:\ -\ |$)))?
    (?:.*?(?<=\ -\ )(?P<y>[^\d,]+)(?=,|$))?
    (?:.*?(?P<z>\d{2}$))?
$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8DrEZd/2/) (and mind the `verbose` [aka x] and `multiline` [aka m] modifier):

---

More verbose:

```
^                       # start of the line
    (?:                 # non capturing parentheses
        (?P<x>\D*?)     # no digits lazily ...
        (?=\ -\ |$)     # up until either " - " or end of string
    )?                  # optional
    (?:
        .*?             # match everything lazily
        (?<=\ -\ )      # pos. lookbehind
        (?P<y>[^\d,]+)  # not a comma or digit
        (?=,|$)         # up until a comma or end of string
    )?
    (?:
        .*?
        (?P<z>\d{2}$)   # two digits at the end
    )?
$
```

Comment: You should remove this non-capturing group: `(?=(?:\ -\ |$))` => `(?=\ -\ |$)`

Comment: Because it is useless.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Right you are, deleted.