# Two patterns in re.compile

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I have text in needs to be matched where it may have P/N or PN , but regular expression have to match both the strings.

Sample Code :

```
PATTERN = re.compile(r'\(USED ON +P\/N {0,1}([^\)]+)')
text = '(USED ON P/N D511835AAB503)'
match = USED_ON_PN_PATTERN.search(text)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
else:
    print('else')
```

Output:

```
D511835AAB503
```

But the code has to match `(USED ON PN D511835AAB503)` also and match.group(1) should return `D511835AAB503`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex how to match an optional character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007302/regex-how-to-match-an-optional-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `?` after the slash character to indicate it is optional.

```py
import re

PATTERN = re.compile(r'\(USED ON +P\/?N {0,1}([^\)]+)')
tests = ['(USED ON P/N D511835AAB503)', '(USED ON PN D511835AAB503)']
for test in tests:
    match = PATTERN.search(test)
    if match:
        print('"{}" matched {}'.format(test, match.group(1)))
    else:
        print('No match in "{}"'.format(test))
```

which outputs

```
"(USED ON P/N D511835AAB503)" matched D511835AAB503
"(USED ON PN D511835AAB503)" matched D511835AAB503
```